# Travis.ci config and execution of npm scripts

Tags: travis-ci, npm-scripts

I'm trying to use Travis for an open source build of a PR. The configuration is quite simple and the logs seem to show that the appropriate modules are installed upon running `yarn install` and I am installing the same version of yarn as that which is used locally. The issue is that when I try to execute the scripts defined in the package.json scripts object the modules are not found when running in Travis. Below is the config and the errors I receive at build time.

```
before_install:
  - curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -s -- --version 1.7.0
  - export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH"
cache:
  yarn: true
  directories:
    - "node_modules"
env:
  - NODE_ENV=production
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 8
  - 9
  - "stable"
install:
  - yarn install
script:
  - yarn run lint
  - yarn test
```

The above producing the following output in the build logs:

```
yarn run v1.7.0
$ ./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/**
/bin/sh: 1: ./node_modules/.bin/eslint: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

The command "yarn run lint" exited with 1.

0.54s$ yarn run test
yarn run v1.7.0
$ ./node_modules/.bin/jest
/bin/sh: 1: ./node_modules/.bin/jest: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

The command "yarn run test" exited with 1.
```

The package.json for this project is as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest",
  "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/**",
  "precommit": "lint-staged",
  "format": "prettier --trailing-comma es5 --single-quote --write 'src/*/*.js' '!(node_modules)/**/*.js'"
},
```

Comment: Have you ever found the solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

Was having the same issue and was able to solve it by doing the following in package.json file

```
      "scripts": {
           "test": "test --passWithNoTests",
             }
```